# External Drive with bitlocker enabled will not eject from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bitlocker, usb-storage, eject

External SSD with bitlocker enabled will not eject from Windows 10, the **mbamagent.exe (bitlocker) is preventing the device from being stopped**.  This also happens with other USB hard drives without bitlocker enabled, but does not happen standard thumb drives.  Standard thumb drives with bitlocker must be ejected from the right click menu in explorer and do not work with the eject feature in the notification area.  SSDs and other USB drives do not have the right click menu item to eject in explorer. also, "**shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL hotplug.dll**" does the same thing. Currently I must shut down the computer to remove them.

Is there a way to force Windows to add the right click eject menu item to explorer?
This might be the solution.

Error when using notification area eject:

[image: Error when using notification area eject]

No Eject menu item in Windows Explorer:

[image: No Eject menu item in Windows' Explorer]

Comment: When examining the driver under Device Manager-Details "Safe removal required" = <false> where thumb drives and SD cards are show "<true>"

Comment: On occasion, I find Windows reluctant to safely eject a USB drive (or other device that needs to be safely shut). Though I use free HotSwap! (http://mt-naka.com/hotswap/index_enu.htm) there a number of similar apps.